# Kotlin or Java - Easy way to Loop through different variables using the index in the variable name

Tags: android, kotlin, for-loop

I'm not sure if the title explains well the issue I'm facing. Maybe an example will help.
I want to programatically add the same background color to different TextView. The names are tv1, tv2, tv3, tv4... Let's say I have 10 Textviews.

Instead of repeating the same line 10 times...

```
tv1.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF)
tv2.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF)
...
```

...I think a loop could be nice. But I'm not sure if it's possible.

Something like...:

```
for (i in 1..10) {
    tv$i.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF)
}
```

Some kind of "interpolation" using the a common prefix + the iterator index as variable name.

As far as I know, interpolation is used in Strings. There's a similar method to be used with variable names? same prefix for all of them + iterator index?

Could someone help me?
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: In practice, you would never create a bunch of properties/variables for similar things like this. You would have them stored in a single List, and then you could iterate the list. What you're describing technically can be achieved with reflection, but no intermediate or advanced programmer would ever use reflection for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tenfour04. Storing them in a List is a simple solution to do what I did what lot of boilerplate code.

It is my first entry in stackoverflow. How can I upvote your answer?

Comment: I only commented instead of adding an answer since it doesn't strictly answer your question. I'll write an answer and you can click the check mark on it to accept it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I upvoted your answer but seems that even it was recorded, I need a better reputation (more questions & answers) before I can do this kind of thinks. Thanks a lot anyway! Have a nice day!

Comment: Upvotes require more reputation, but you should always be able to put a check mark next to the answer that was most helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is known as [an XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) because you're asking for a solution to a problem that shouldn't exist in the first place if you take a step back and address the root problem.

In practice, you would never create a bunch of properties/variables for similar things like this. You would have them stored in a single List, and then you could iterate the list. What you're describing technically can be achieved with reflection, but no intermediate or advanced programmer would ever use reflection for that purpose. Reflection is for things like libraries that analyze code and can generate interfaces implementations for you. It's not practical in general application code and violates object-oriented programming principles.

Here's an example of creating a list of TextViews that you could iterate.

```
// Lazy property since findViewById can only be called after setContentView().
// Alternative: Use a lateinit var and put the generating code in onCreate() instead.
private val myTextViews: List<TextView> by lazy {
    listOf(R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2, etc).map { findViewById<TextView>(it) }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to store your `TextView` in a list and then iterate over it.

```
val list = mutableListOf(tv1, tv2, tv3)
for(tv in list)
    tv.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF.toInt())
```